# How to configure a connection factory in Foreign JMS Server in weblogic 10.3 to avtiveMQXAConnectionFactory

Tags: java

I am using EJB 2.1 and weblogic 10.3.
Am facing an issue with transactionality and am trying to configure my connection factory to ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.

I have setup my weblogic using this link.

http://amadei.com.br/blog/index.php/connecting-weblogic-and-activemq

I am using an MDB listener